# Inside a MongoDB find function, I callback and use a res.redirect, I get a cannot set header error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I'm trying to search for a user/shop account in my database (mongoDB) and then either refresh the login page but with some errors, or send them to their required page.

So far sending them to their required page works, however I get this error message from my Node console when trying to res.redirect to the /signin page.

```
throw err;
      ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Here is the actual code

```
//Rendering Signin Page
app.get('/signin', function(req, res) {
    res.render('signin', {
        err: false,
    })
});

//Rendering Signin Page with err
app.get('/signin/err', function(req, res) {
    res.render('signin',{
        err: true,
    })
});


app.post('/signin', function(req, res) {
    let data  = req.body;
    User.find({email: data.email},'_id email password', function(err, docs) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {


            //Finding the matching user
            for(i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
                if(data.password == docs[i].password) {
                    res.redirect('/'+docs[i]._id + '/userhome')
                }
            }

            if(docs.length === 0) {
                console.log('no user found')
                res.redirect('/signin/err');
                return;
            }
        }
    })
    Shop.find({email: data.email}, '_id email password', function(err,docs) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {

            //Finding the matching user
            for(i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
                if(data.password == docs[i].password) {
                    res.redirect('/'+docs[i]._id + '/shophome')
                }
            }

            if(docs.length === 0) {
                console.log('no shop found')
                res.redirect('/signin/err')
                break;
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Also here is the Pug file I'm trying to render (I don't think this is the issue)

```
doctype html
html
    head    
        title uShop
        //Bootstrap CSS
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous")
        script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js', integrity='sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo', crossorigin='anonymous')
        script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js', integrity='sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1', crossorigin='anonymous')
        script(src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', integrity='sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM', crossorigin='anonymous')
    body
        nav(class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top") 
            a(class="navbar-text" style="font-size:175%; color:white; padding:0px" href="/") uShop.com
        h1(class="display-2 text-center position-relative" style="top: 3rem; font-size: 400%") Sign In
        form(action="/signin" method="POST")
            div(class="form-row position-relative" style="top:7rem")
                label(class="col-lg-4 col-form-label position-relative text-right" for="inputEmail" style="font-size: 150%; top:-5px; left: -5px;") Email:
                input(class="form-control col-lg-4" type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail")
            //- if err == true
            //-     div(class="invalid-feedback") email incorrect
            br
            div(class="form-row position-relative" style="top:7rem")
                label(class="col-lg-4 col-form-label position-relative text-right" for="inputPassword" style="font-size: 150%; top:-5px; left: -5px;") Password:
                input(class="form-control col-lg-4" type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword")
            div(class="form-row position-relative" style="top:8rem")
                input(class="btn btn-primary btn-lg offset-lg-4 " type="submit" value="Sign In")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/signin', function (req, res) {
    let data = req.body;
    User.find({ email: data.email }, '_id email password', function (err, docs) {
        res.redirect('/' + ...);
    })
    Shop.find({ email: data.email }, '_id email password', function (err, docs) {
        res.redirect('/' + ...);
    });
})
```

`res.redirect` cannot run twice in each request, but, from your couse, at least called twice

---

**How about this?**

```
app.post('/signin', function (req, res) {

  let data = req.body;
    User.find({ email: data.email }, '_id email password', function (err, docs) {
        // res.redirect('/' + ...);

        Shop.find({ email: data.email }, '_id email password', function (err, docs) {
            res.redirect('/' + ...);
        });
    });
})
```

---

**Also, ???**

You need redirect to
`'/' + docs[i]._id + '/shophome'`
 and
`'/' + docs[0]._id + '/userhome'`
in  `signin API` at onece(one request)?

I think, this is impossable with http(rest api) request, 
and `nodejs` and other language is same.

Also, I think, this is purpose of `normal user`.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to search in either `user` or `shop` collection.

1. Add `async/await` it will make your code more readable

```
app.post('/signin', async function(req, res) {
....
})
```

2. You need to use `findOne` for both collection search and using`email` and `password` both in search params so no further password check needed in code

```
const userResult = await User.findOne({ email: data.email, password: data.password }, '_id email password');
const shopResult = await Shop.findOne({ email: data.email, password: data.password }, '_id email password');
```

3. As `findOne` returns `object` as a result if `email` and `password` matches.
   You can check that if both results are empty then redirect as below

```
if(!userResult && !shopResult) {
  return res.redirect('/signin/err');
}

if(userResult) {
  return res.redirect('/'+userResult._id + '/userhome')
}

if(shopResult) {
  return res.redirect('/'+shopResult._id + '/shophome')
}
```

Adding `return` on reach `redirect` will ensure that code execution has ended at that point.

Use `try/catch` to log unwanted errors.

MND link for `async/await` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the response. I'm not too familiar with async/await but I'll have a look at the documentation.